# Why are my sparks not animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, animation

I have, at http://blajeny.com, the following code meant to animate several sparks dancing away from a user click on the screen:

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event_object)
    {
    var number_of_sparks = 6 + Math.round(6 * Math.random());
    for(var index = 0; index < number_of_sparks; ++index)
        {
        spark(event_object.pageX, event_object.pageY);
        }
    });

function move_spark(image, angle, increment, speed, x, y)
    {
    console.log('angle: ' + angle + ', increment: ' + increment + ', speed: '
      + speed);
    my_angle = angle + (Math.random() - Math.random()) / 10;
    var velocity_x = Math.round(Math.cos(angle) * speed);
    var velocity_y = Math.round(Math.sin(angle) * speed);
    image.style.top = (y - 10 + velocity_y) + 'px';
    image.style.left = (x - 10 + velocity_x) + 'px';
    my_increment = increment + 1;
    if (increment > 10)
        {
        image.style.opacity = (20 - my_increment) / 10;
        }
    if (image.style.opacity < .01)
        {
        document.body.removeChild(image);
        }
    else
        {
        setTimeout(function()
            {
            move_spark(image, my_angle, my_increment, speed, x, y);
            }, 100);
        }
    }

function spark(x, y)
    {
    var increment = 0;
    var image_object = new Image();
    var angle = 2 * 3.1416 * Math.random();
    var speed = 7 * Math.random() + 7 * Math.random() + 7 * Math.random();
    image_object.onload = function()
        {
        image_object.style.position = 'absolute';
        image_object.style.zIndex = 1;
        image_object.style.top = (y - 10) + 'px';
        image_object.style.left = (x - 10) + 'px';
        }
    image_object.src = '/img/spark.png';
    document.body.appendChild(image_object);
    console.log('Before move_spark: ');
    move_spark(image_object, angle, increment, speed, x, y);
    }
```

If I don't run the animation, a click leaves a "spark mark" centered where it is intended to be. However, if I attempt the animation I don't see anything, and the log doesn't seem to show the animation. The intent is to make an animation that will move for two seconds, fading to invisible in the second second.

What can be done to correct this code?

Comment: What sparks, all I see is some annoying cube ?

Comment: @adeneo OP said sparks don't appear... Or you really need those reading glasses? ; ).

Comment: @Teemu - Oh okay, I really do need glasses. +1 to me for at least taking the effort to visit the site!

Comment: "in the second second" Oh english language, you so silly. How are you starting the animation without clicking? I only see things being fired from the click.

Comment: @adeneo Please don't worry about your eyes, I couldn't see any sparks at that page too... Just going through all sources...

Comment: @Jack, the effect is intended as a click effect. If the user clicks in the screen, a few sparks shoot out. Or that is the intent; clearly enough not happening yet.

Answer (score 0):

You were not setting the opacity so the object never showed up in the collection

when you checked for opacity here:

```
    if (image.style.opacity < .01) {
        document.body.removeChild(image);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            move_spark(image, my_angle, increment, speed, x, y);
        }, 100);
    }
```

it was blank not a number.

So I fixed it by adding opacity to the image_object.

[Here is how it appears to be working, but I am not sure it is what you wanted.](http://jsfiddle.net/UyGFv/)

I also made some tweaks to the code. you had a few redundant variables.

I am not sure what you meant to do but I think [this looks a little better](http://jsfiddle.net/UyGFv/2/).